# XSLT and recursion to generate table

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I'm new to XSLT and am having some problems trying to format an XML document which has recursive nodes.

There have 2 styles of tree node which are group and data.

The problem is my current XSLT template unable to generate the content when the Nodes have mixed of group and data styles.

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="Nodes[TreeNode]">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="TreeNode" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Nodes[not(TreeNode)]" />

  <xsl:template match="TreeNode[Style='Data']">
      <!--<table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Value</th>
         </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>-->
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <!--</tbody>
      </table>-->
  </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="TreeNode[Style='Group']">
    <group>
      <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="Label"/>
      </p> 
         <xsl:apply-templates select="Nodes" />
    </group>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TreeNode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Label>Root</Label>
  <Style>Group</Style>
  <Nodes>
    <TreeNode>
      <Label>A</Label>
      <Style>Group</Style>
      <Nodes>
        <TreeNode>
          <Label>B</Label>
          <Style>Group</Style>
          <Nodes>
            <TreeNode>
              <Label />
              <Value>AAA</Value>
              <Style>Data</Style>
              <Nodes />
            </TreeNode>
            <TreeNode>
              <Label />
              <Value>BBB</Value>
              <Style>Data</Style>
              <Nodes />
            </TreeNode>
          </Nodes>
        </TreeNode>
        <TreeNode>
          <Label>C</Label>
          <Style>Group</Style>
          <Nodes>
            <TreeNode>
              <Label />
              <Value>CCC</Value>
              <Style>Data</Style>
              <Nodes />
            </TreeNode>
            <TreeNode>
              <Label />
              <Value>DDD</Value>
              <Style>Data</Style>
              <Nodes />
            </TreeNode>
          </Nodes>
        </TreeNode>
        <TreeNode>
          <Label>D</Label>
          <Style>Group</Style>
          <Nodes>
            <TreeNode>
              <Label />
              <Value>EEE</Value>
              <Style>Data</Style>
              <Nodes />
            </TreeNode>
          </Nodes>
        </TreeNode>
      </Nodes>
    </TreeNode>
  </Nodes>
</TreeNode>
```

Expected Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two templates at the start of your XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="Nodes[TreeNode]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="TreeNode" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Nodes[not(TreeNode)]" />
```

These could actually be merged into one; like so:

```
<xsl:template match="Nodes">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="TreeNode" />
</xsl:template>
```

The reason being is that if `Nodes` does not have a `TreeNode` under it, then `<xsl:apply-templates select="TreeNode" />` will not select anything anyway, so the effect is the same. (In fact, you could drop this template entirely if `Nodes` could only ever have `TreeNode` under it, as XSLT's built-in templates will do the same thing).

However, in answer to your problem, is that what I think you need is another template that you need another template that matches `Nodes` in the case where there is a child `TreeNode` for "Data"

```
<xsl:template match="Nodes[TreeNode/Style='Data']">
  <table>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="TreeNode" />
  </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="Nodes[TreeNode/Style='Data']">
      <table>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="TreeNode" />
      </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Nodes">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="TreeNode" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TreeNode[Style='Data']">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="TreeNode[Style='Group']">
    <group>
      <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="Label"/>
      </p> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Nodes" />
    </group>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Tim, are you working on C# development? I may zip you the small project since I have tried many times to solve this problem.

Comment: pls feel free drop me an email, tenghonloon@hotmail.com